# What if classical and quantum probabilities were not independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-states

Isham in his *Lectures on Quantum Theory* Chapter 6, *Technical Developments* states that for a mixed state $\rho=(\psi_1,\dots,\psi_D;w_1,\dots,w_D)$ and an observable A with an eigenvalue $a_n$, $$\text{Prob}(A=a_n;\rho)=\sum_{d=1}^Dw_d\text{ Prob}(A=a_n;|\psi_d\rangle),$$ based "on the assumption that that quantum-mechanical and classical probabilities are independent of each other."

**Question:** What would the expression above look like if the probabilities were *not* independent?

Comment: I guess the $w_d$ could not simply be factored out. So there would not be a simple expression using just a density matrix. But what really interests me is **In which way could these probabilities be dependent?**

Comment: I don't think this assumption is needed but it depends a little how you prepare the mixture. Well on second thought it's also ok to spell it out

Comment: I agree with @DoctorNuu that we would not have a density matrix to talk about if these probabilities were somehow mixed, because the density matrix is _constructed_ from a classical ensemble over quantum states.